# Multiple equation number for a single equation with multiple labels to be referenced by

Tags: pdftex

Multiple equation numbers can be assigned to single equation using the following code and also the equation numbering is continues and how can this equation with multiple equation number can be assigned multiple labels that can be used to reference this  equation?

[image]

The equation numbers can be coded using this code,  when it comes to labeling the equation it does not take even a single label.

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
a+u=34
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} 
a+u=34
\tag{\refstepcounter{equation}\theequation,\refstepcounter{equation}\theequation,\refstepcounter{equation}\theequation}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:5}
a+u=34
\end{equation}

The equation \ref{eq:1} and equation (\ref{eq:2}) to \ref{eq:4} are not refered as it number is displayed in the pdf

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry I could not understand what is the problem and what you want to do. Can you please rephrase again more clearly what you want to do in the comments here?

Comment: @hesham I want to add multiple equation number to a single equation but i am unable to give it labels

Comment: @hesham The above code can give multiple equation number as you can see it has provide equation no. (2,3,4) but how to label this equation with e.q \label(eq:2) & \label(eq:3) & \label(eq:4)  ?

Comment: Could you explain the use case for assigning more than than one equation number to a single equation? For instance, is there a difference in meaning if the equation is cross-referenced as "Equation (2)", "Equation (3)", or "Equation (4)"?

Comment: @mico My case is that i have Multiple matrix equation so when i multiply them it give me multiple number of equations so that is why i am giving multiple equation number and i need to have multiple label as well to reference them

Comment: You can then write a single equation with for example label 2, and then when you cross reference it, you can say that Eq. 2 is obtained 3 times out of the multiplication of the said matrices.

Comment: @hesham If you have a more proper solution it would be good because i have completed my whole document and I don't want to change my interpretations?

Comment: The cross references `\ref{eq:2}` and `\ref{eq:4}` will definitely always throw an error or warning (`??`) in the output because the commands `\label{eq:2}` and `\label{eq:4}` are never defined in the code.